# Summarize Historical Uptime Data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm finishing my first asp.net web app and I've encountered a difficult problem. The web app is designed to test network devices at various locations across the country and record the response time. A Windows service checks these devices regularly, typically every 1-10 minutes. The results of each check are then recorded in a SQL Server table with this design. (ResponseTime is NULL when the device is down.)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeviceStatuses] (

[DeviceStatusID] INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[DeviceID]       INT      NOT NULL,
[StatusTime]     DATETIME NULL,
[ResponseTime]   INT      NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DeviceStatuses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DeviceStatusID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_DeviceStatuses_Devices] FOREIGN KEY ([DeviceID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Devices] ([DeviceID])
);
```

The service has been running for a couple months, with a minimal number of devices and the table has about 500,000 rows. The client would like to have access to a 3-month rolling downtime summary for each device. Something along the lines of:

Down Times:
12/11/2012 3:20 PM - 3:42 PM
12/20/2012 1:00 AM - 9:00 AM

To the best of my understanding I need to get the StatusTime for the beginning and end of each block of NULL ResponseTimes, for a particular DeviceID of course. I've done several searches on Google and StackOverflow, but haven't found anything that resembles what I'm trying to do. (Maybe I'm not using the right search terms.) My brother, a much more experienced programmer, suggested that I might be able to use a CURSOR in SQL Server, though he acknowledged that CURSOR performance is terrible and it would need to be a scheduled task. Any recommendations?

Comment: Check this out; you may be in luck: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213234.aspx

Comment: Thanks @JonSeigel, those functions look very helpful, and I wish I knew more SQL to put them to use.

Comment: You need to seach on 'Islands and Gaps'. You are in luck as SQL Server 2012 finally has some useful windowing functions that you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare  @DeviceStatuses table(

[DeviceStatusID] INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[DeviceID]       INT      NOT NULL,
[StatusTime]     DATETIME NULL,
[ResponseTime]   INT      NULL)


Insert into @DeviceStatuses([DeviceID],[StatusTime],[ResponseTime])
Values
(1,'20120101 10:10',2),(1,'20120101 10:12',NULL),(1,'20120101 10:14',2),
(1,'20120102 10:10',2),(1,'20120102 10:12',NULL),(1,'20120102 10:14',2),
(2,'20120101 10:10',2),(2,'20120101 10:12',NULL),(2,'20120101 10:14',2),
(2,'20120101 10:19',2),(2,'20120101 10:20',NULL),(2,'20120101 10:21',NULL),(2,'20120101 10:22',2),
(2,'20120102 10:10',2),(2,'20120102 10:12',NULL),(2,'20120102 10:14',2);

Select [DeviceID],MIN([StatusTime]) as StartDown,MAX([StatusTime]) as EndDown
from
(
Select [DeviceID],[StatusTime]
,(Select MAX([StatusTime]) from @DeviceStatuses s2 where s2.DeviceID=s1.DeviceID and s2.StatusTime<s1.StatusTime and s2.ResponseTime is not null) as gr
from @DeviceStatuses s1
where s1.ResponseTime is null
)a
Group by [DeviceID],gr
order by [DeviceID],gr
```

Comment: Thanks @bummi! This is great. I'm still looking it over to make sure I understand what's going on, but it appears to work perfectly and only takes about 30 sec. to execute for all devices.